# Can you pass a React useState state object into a Styled Component that's using Tailwind and twin.macro?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, tailwind-css, use-state

The following Vue code works. I'm trying to translate it to React. The key functionality I'm interested in is the ability to toggle tailwind classes with a change in state. In this case, with a boolean that toggles whether a div is shown or hidden by changing Tailwind's property for display from block to hidden:

```
<template>
  <header>

    <button @click="isOpen = !isOpen" type="button" class="...">My Button</button> // toggle state

    <div :class"isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'" class="px-2 pt-2 pb-4"> //show and hide div

  </header>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isOpen: false, // set state
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Here's where I'm at in React using Tailwindcss and twin.macro (a combination of Tailwind and Styled Components) using React's useState Hook:

```
export default function Header() {

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false); // declare state

  return (

    <Wrapper>

      <ButtonWrap type="button" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}> // toggle state

        My Button

      </ButtonWrap>

      <StyledDiv>How do I toggle a style in this?</StyledDiv> // show and hide div

    </Wrapper>
  )
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
${tw`container shadow`};
`
const ButtonWrap = styled.button`
${tw`block text-mycolor hover:text-myothercolor focus:text-myothercolor`}
`
const StyledDiv= styled.div<Props>`
display: ${(props) => props.myProp ? 'block' : 'hidden'; // Does NOT work
`
```

Obviously this does not work as it's using a prop and not state, and with Tailwind as you cannot use display:block/hidden.

Please note, the problem is not hiding the div, that's easy up in the JSX:

```
  {isOpen && (
     <StyledDiv> ... </StyledDiv>
  )}
```

I need the solution to change a Tailwind class in the Styled Component itself if possible. I'm not sure if it's possible as the state is not a prop and I understand that Styled Components are stateless. I'm new to SC, so maybe there's an easy solution I'm missing.